# Need a team checklist/workflow application

Tags: web-apps, software-development, project-management, cms, collaboration

We have several processes that we want everyone on the team to follow. The process could be slightly different depending on the task, and it would be great to be able to see a high-level chart showing everyone's progress toward a specific goal, including remaining times. Is there any software that does this at a fine-grained level?

For instance, I might have Joe working on Issue #48 that involves the following process:

1. Create branch in Git. (0.1 h)
2. Make code changes. (2.0 h)
3. Make sure file headers are updated. (0.1 h)
4. Run static analysis tool. (0.5 h)
5. Publish peer review package. (0.5 h)
6. Notify Bob that fix is available. (0.1 h)
7. Conduct review. (1.0 h)
8. Incorporate actions from review. (0.5 h)
9. Push changes to remote. (0.1 h)
10. Close ticket. (0.1 h)

Joe could follow the process as displayed and check-off each item as he completes it. He could also update estimated times and undo the checks if he has to rework anything.

Tom might have the exact same steps for Issue #56 except his code changes are estimated at 6.0 h.

Notice how low-level and fine-grained each of these items is, but they all add up to a significant amount of time.

It would be great if the software ran on a central server that everyone would access via a Web page, and that I could log-in also to see some sort of a bar chart showing the progress for each component.

For instance, if Issues 48, 50, and 51 were all meant for Gobbledygook 1.0, then I could see a bar chart on the total progress of Gobbledygook 1.0.

We already use JIRA and similar tools to track individual defects, but that's too high-level for what I want. I don't want one issue for each of the ten items listed above.

We also maintain schedules in Project. That, too, is too high-level for what I want. Again I don't want each of the ten items as a separate line item.

**EDIT:** Modified:

Windows would be required if it's locally installed on a desktop PC; otherwise, if it's hosted on another computer on the Intranet, it could be on Linux. It would definitely need to be downloaded and installed; it can't be used from outside the Intranet.

Comment: Have you tried changing JIRA flow?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? It might be exactly what I am searching for as well.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [ToDoList](http://abstractspoon.weebly.com/)? It might work for you:

- you can create a task with as many sub tasks as you want,
- you can put a time estimate for how long each of the tasks/sub tasks will take (and you can change the estimate as you go along),
- you can allocate tasks to different users, assign a due date, priority and set up reminders,
- you can track the time you are taking to complete each task,
- you can tick each task individually once you finish it,
- there is no progress bar view to visualize task/subtask completion, but you can put a percentage of how far along your task is (if you divide your task into multiple subtasks, the percentage of their completion will be reflected in the overall percentage of the main task they belong to),
- (the views available are: task tree, list view, Burndown, calendar, Gantt chart and Kanban),
- it's a desktop software that runs on Windows, it [should run on Linux](http://abstractspoon.com/wiki/doku.php?id=linux) as well though,
- I think you can also [sync it between different machines](http://abstractspoon.com/wiki/doku.php?id=multi-user-prefs#simple_source_control) via LAN.
  Overall, I thought it was quite a good piece of software, so maybe worth a look.

**Full disclosure: I am in NO way, shape or form connected to the creators of the ToDoList software.** I know many of my answers direct people towards it. This is simply because I think it is really elegant and powerful and because from my reading and understanding of the questions asked, I believe it can respond to the needs of the askers best.

Answer (score 1):

Trello or ClockingIT seem good options. check at http://amplarede.com.br/utilitarios/agendas-e-organizadores . although the site is in portuguese, the links are in english.

Answer (score 1):

[Liquid Planner](http://www.liquidplanner.com/) sounds like it could be something worth looking at for you.

A typical use case involves making a project from a template, modifying it if necessary for the project and then assigning a user and expected times for each task. It then displays a timeline and current progress compared to the deadlines.

It adds a separate line for each task, but as an expandable view from an overview of all projects: ie you can have a high or low level view as required.

I'm not aware of an ability to install it locally, I believe it's just a web-based service.

If you want something simpler, Teamwork is roughly similar but without the visible timeline and with a much simpler view - it's more of a straightforward checklist of minor tasks. It doesn't (as far as I remember) allow you to store expected time, but it can be added as a comment or in the title (eg taskName 5h). It does allow you to enter the actual time taken.